# Making a request to AWS for an increase of number of available GSIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the maximum number of GSIs you have used?  The current limit is 20. However, AWS allows you to request additional GSIs. Has anyone requested more than 20? What is the maximum number of GSIs will AWS allow on request?

Comment: I have no experience attempting to increase the limit on GSIs so I don't know the answer but I can imagine such a need sometimes being driven by a relational DB mindset which is at odds with NoSQL. Not saying that's the case here, I have no idea, but may be true for some future readers in which case I would recommend a deeper dive into DynamoDB modeling ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6-qWdsa8a4)).

Comment: I have heard this argument before. The relational mindset is being applied to DDB. But in this case, there is a legit reason.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-secondary-indexes) doesn't list a maximum. So if there is a maximum Amazon doesn't want us to know what it is.

Comment: @MarkB yes it does ["For maximum query flexibility, you can create up to 20 global secondary indexes (default quota) and up to 5 local secondary indexes per table."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)

Comment: @Charles that's just listing the default limits. The link I posted says you can have more than 20 if you file a request, but it doesn't say anything about a maximum. "There is an initial quota of 20 global secondary indexes per table. To request a service quota increase, see https://aws.amazon.com/support."

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer from someone I know.

They did receive an increase to 30 GSIs.

Update: this is anecdotal info from a friend of a friend but their enterprise app got approved for 50,000 GSIs.

Comment: 50,000? Wow! This means that every write to the base table will cause 50,000 writes to the indexes. With on-demand pricing, this will cost you 6.25 cents per write. With reserved capacity, you need to pay 50,000 times more than the base table's reserved capacity. How are these prices realistic?